# How to save previous location in React Router after Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a `ReactTable` component which accepts an `onRowClick` callback function as a property.

I use this component to list an array of `Purchase` objects. On click of any `Purchase` (row), I want the user to be redirected from `/purchases/` to `/purchases/:order_number`. I am currently doing this by setting a `redirect` state to the order number, and conditionally rendering a `Redirect` compoennt:

```
const Purchases:React.FC<> = ({}) => {
   const Purchases: Array<Purchase> = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.shop.purchases)
   const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState<string | null>(null)

   return (
     <Fragment>
       <TableContainer
          total={null}
          data={Purchases}
          hide={[]}
          onRowClick={(row, idx) => {
            setRedirect("/purchase/" + row["Order Number"])
          }}
        />
       {redirect !== null ? <Redirect to={redirect} /> : null}
     </Fragment>
  )
}
```

The problem is, after I go to `/purchase/:order_number`, I cannot go back to the previous page because `Redirect` does not push to history, it just sets the current route to the next (the one specified in the `to` prop). Is there any way to solve this properly?

The version of React Router Dom I am using is `5.2.0` which does NOT support the `Navigate` component mentioned in the answer on the question marked as duplicate.

After implementing the solution provided in this question and trying some of the answers from the "duplicate" marked question, I discovered that these solutions actually do NOT WORK!!!

If the user is redirected from `routeA` to `routeB` and uses a `NavLink` to go to `routeC`, after clicking the Back button, instead of going back to `routeB`, the user is taken to `routeA`. This also happens even if the user goes from `routeB` to `routeC` and then to `routeD`....

Comment: Since the "duplicate" uses React Router Dom v6 and I use v5.2.0, this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: regarding your now deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436653/mysql-error-inserting-date-value-when-working-with-a-materialized-view-and-a-tri?noredirect=1#comment133105426_75436653 - You wrote "The solution is to change BEFORE INSERT to AFTER INSERT" - however, your question had an after insert trigger, not a before insert one, so nobody could possibly have suggested this solution. I think the problem is that you used `date = <expression>` format to assign value to the date column. This is evaluated as boolean expression (is date field == expression), not as date.

Comment: @Shadow Yes I see, you're completely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this is to somehow store the current location, or find a way to pass it to the next one via the `location` property.

You can simply use `local storage`, but I'd suggest passing the location in the state via the `Redirect` component:

```
const location: string = useLocation<{ pathname: string }>().pathname

<Redirect to={{
  pathname: "/purchase/12345",
  state: { prevLocation: location }
}} />
```

Then in the component which is rendered on the route `/purhcase/:order_number`, you'd use the `useHistory` hook provided by `react-router-dom`, accept the `location` property and have a `useEffect` and an event listener which listens for the `popstate` event, and run `history.push` with the proper location whenever the `popstate` event is triggered:

```
const PurchasePage: React.FC<{ location: { state: { prevLocation: string } } }> = ({ location }) => {
  const history = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => history.push(location.state.prevLocation))
    return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', () => history.push(location.state.prevLocation))
  }, [history])

  return <SomeJsxComponent />
}
```

This way, you pass the location via `props` to the next component which is rendered after the `Redirect` and intercept the `back` button in order to push to history the previous location.